# Harris & Harris Debt Collector is harrassing me

Tags: debt, debt-collection

I'm getting several robocalls (automated calls) from Harris & Harris Debt Collectors saying that I owe a debt but they won't tell me any more information.  I don't know how to stop them.  I found that this is happening to many other people from this post http://badfinance.org/profile/823/harris-harris-ltd and http://badfinance.org/review/1924253/harris-harris-ltd-debt-collection

Comment: Does the call offer an option for you to "press 1 to be connected to an agent", or at least give you a number to call or a way to contact them?

Comment: Why the close vote ? If anybody wants any extra information, do clarify in the comments for the OP to add more information.

Comment: Can we assume US? what contact info did they leave? Have you contacted them?

Comment: What's their phone number? You can post it in a comment here.

Comment: When Harris & Harris robocalls me (for no apparent reason) they list the number (312) 604-7103

Answer (score 4):

You should check your credit report. Sometimes debt collection shows up on your credit report. If you do this, you will hopefully be able to see what is causing them to call you. If you find that the debt has already been paid, you can send them proof and then send documentation to all of the credit bureaus as well to dispute the claim.

Answer (score 2):

Document the calls, then sue them in small claims court for $1,500 per call, the Federal limit for illegal robo calls.

Once they get the summons they might contact you and be willing to make a deal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you record the calls?  You might need them as evidence in the future.  If you sue them for harassment or anything like that.

There are a lot of websites where you can check your credit report free of charge.  One of the best options is annualcreditreport.com

You should look through your credit report and make a list of all the debts it mentions.  And look in your records to find out if all those debts are valid.  If any are old, you should find out the statute of limitations for collecting them in court.

Comment: annualcreditreport.com is the only one actually endorsed by the US government.  The rest of them are privately owned and scam you (well, work some sort of business angle on you) in some way.  The semi-legit ones will charge you fees or sell your name to marketing companies, the nasty ones are fraudsters trying to get you to enter your personal info, slam malware onto your PC, etc.  Even if they are semi-legit, they can be hacked and then the hackers have your info.